# Executing a bash command line inside a python function

Tags: python, bash, command-line

I want to implement a python function to execute a bash command.
for example:

```
def run_command():
# run 'python test --a' command
```

Comment: Have you done any research whosever?

Comment: You might want/need to make sure Bash runs it, like `bash -c 'python test --a'`, depending on the method you choose (see duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("--command here--")
```